# Saving large amount of data on a IOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is the first time that I'm programming for IOS and I'm still learning using one of the udemy courses.

At this moment I'm trying to create an Iphone app that makes a calculation of how much an employee should receive in a certain day, based on the amount of hours that employee worked. At the end of each mouth, the application should sum the value of all the saved days and show how much that employee must receive that month.

So my problem is: in the course that I'm learning, they store the data using the function

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(something, forKey: "something")
```

but I don't think this is the right way of storing big amount of data.

My idea was more a less creating a database to store the data instead of doing the function UserDefaults(just like in android there is, for example, SQLite) but I also don't know if this is the right way of doing it.

So my real question is: what is the right way of storing large amount of data in an IOS App?

Comment: How large is large? And what exactly do you think is wrong with using user defaults? A file is a file is a file. You could store directly as a file, you could use SQLite, you could use Core Data, but you're _still_ just writing the data to disk, just like UserDefaults does, so what's the problem you think you're going to solve by not using UserDefaults?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what is the more correct way. My idea is to create like a table with an id for each record.

Comment: But what does "more correct" even mean? Your "table with an id for each record" could be a dictionary, and you can store a dictionary in UserDefaults, so I ask again: what's the problem you're really trying to solve? That's what you should be asking about — the _actual use case_, not some general meaningless notion of "the right way".

Comment: The thing is, in android, you have a function called SharedPreferences but that function is not suppose to save large amount of that. In my example, I would not use SharedPreferences to store data from each day of work, you would use something like SQLite to do that. Since I'm a newbie programming in IOS, I thought UserDefaults was something like SharedPreferences and there was another way of saving data

Comment: It might be and there might be. But until we know what's in this dictionary and how big it is, there's no telling what's "best". The thing is, there's a way to ask a question on Stack Overflow. That wasn't it. The question you _did_ ask has been asked many times, so you got shut down as a duplicate.